# How to get component parameters?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a problem here and just cant solve it :-/

I am developing an Joomla component with backend.
In the backend I set a parameter, the `dashboardId`, but I can't access them in the view. I always get `data:protected` (when I dump `params`). It seems like I'm not allowed to access the object.

Here is the `default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Dashboard">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[dashboard LAYOUT DESCRIPTION]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="params">
            <field
                name="dashboardId" 
                type="text" 
                label="Dashboard ID"
                description="com_dashboard_desc"
                default="1"
            >   
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</metadata>
```

Now, in the `view.html.php` I try to access the parameter like this:

```
$app = &JFactory::getApplication();
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_dashboard');
$dashboardId = $params->get('dashboardId');
var_dump($dashboardId);
```

When I do `var_dump($dashboardId);` I get `NULL` but when I dump `$app`, I can see the `dashboardID`

every help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Thats the message wenn I dump $params: object(JRegistry)#102 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#106 (0) { } } ... and I want to access the data object

Answer (score 65):

There's a more simple way.
First import Joomla Component Helper:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper'); // not required in Joomla 3.x
```

And then retrieve any attribute you want like this:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_dashboard');
$dashboardID = $params->get('dashboardID');
```

Greetings.

Comment: This is the best way to do it in J!2.5 and > (so far)

Comment: This is the correct way, as you will see most properties in Joomla is protected [var_dump($params) will reveal this to you] and the only way to access them is via a function call.

Answer (score 12):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$componentParams = $app->getParams('com_example');
$param = $componentParams->get('paramName', defaultValue);
```

Comment: This is probably not work in the backend because `JFactory::getApplication('site')` will still return an administration application object which does not have the method `getParams`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the answer provided by LoboX, I'd recommend using the component helper to get component parameters:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper'); // Import component helper library
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams(JRequest::getVar('option')); // Get parameter helper (corrected 'JRquest' spelling)
$params->get('parameter_name'); // Get an individual parameter
```

The `JRequest::getVar('option')` returns your component's name with the com_ prefix.  Aside from that, it looks like you're trying to mix a little bit of 1.5/1.6 syntax into your configuration file.  If you haven't seen it yet, try reading through the [2.5 version](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_13) of the documentation.  I hope that helps!

Comment: As pointed out by aspirisen, JRequest is deprecated in Joomla 3.x, and has been replaced by JInput. The syntax for that would be something like this:
`JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('option','');`

Since I posted the original answer I've come to the conclusion that it's probably better to use the hard-coded string like in several other answers unless you're doing a lot of coding and can't be bothered to lock it down instead of grabbing it from the request parameters, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is simular to J.T. Blum answer, but in Joomla 3.x JRequest is depricated. It is another way to get the apllication's params.

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $input = $app ->input;
    $componentName = $input ->get('option');
    $params = JComponentHelper::getParams($componentName);
    print_r($params);
```

Comment: to get a param you must use `$params ->get('param name');`

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.1 Joomla is in process to deprecate all `J` classes, matter effect, version 4.0 will deprecate almost all `J` classes, the recommended way from now on to retrieve components param is either calling the entire namespace function:

```
Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::getParams('com_dashboard')->get('dashboardID');
```

or, if you are working on a model, you can call `use` keyword in order to import the file and use the class down in the document, like

```
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;

function myFunction() {
    $param = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_dashboard');
    $dashboardID = $param->get('dashboardID');
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for 2021 so far.

Comment: Use this if using J3 or higher

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I only got the **data:protected** result until I went to the configuration of my component and saved it. Though there were default values printed in the textfields Joomla wasn't able to read them before clicking on 'save'.

Answer (score 1):

Helper Function to get Params Object in all Joomla Versions 1.5 / 2.5 /3.x

```
class myCompoHelper{

    public static function getParams($option)
    {

        if (version_compare(JVERSION, '1.5', 'g'))
        {
            $application = JFactory::getApplication();
            if ($application->isSite())
            {
                $params = $application->getParams($option);
            }
            else
            {
                jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
                $params = JComponentHelper::getParams($option);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
            $params = JComponentHelper::getParams($option);
        }
        return $params;
    }

}

$params=myCompoHelper::getParams('com_mycomponent');
echo $params->get('myParamName',null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the solution was this:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$parametername = $input->getInt('parametername');
echo $parametername;
```

This is the name of a parameter in the default.xml in the views tmpl folder.
here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Offers">
         <message>This is a component in order to display offers</message>
    </layout>
    <state>
        <name>name</name>
            <description>description</description>

        <url addpath="/administrator/components/com_component/elements">
            <param name="category_id" section="com_component" type="categoriesmenu"  value_field="category_name" label="COM_COMPONENT_CATEGORY_FIELD_SELECT_TITLE" description="COM_COMPONENT_CATEGORY_FIELD_SELECT_TITLE_DESC" />
        </url>
    </state>

    <fields name="request" >
        <fieldset name="request" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_component/models/fields">
            <field name="parametername" type="category"
                label="category"
                required="true"
                description="Perigrafh"
            />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>


</metadata>
```